# Login failed for user 'sa' in ASP.NET with SQL Server 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, named-instance

I am trying to connect my .NET project to SQL Server developer edition 2019 (named instance), but it always throw the error:

> Login failed for user 'sa'.

It however connects perfectly through SSMS without any issues.

I tried all possible things as suggested over internet but could not make my website run, is it actually the named instance which causes this issue, or it's issue at large.

I am able to connect my project if i connect to my database located on the remote server. but the one on my local machine just does not works.

Here's how my connection string looks like

```
server=[machine]\\[instance]; Integrated Security=SSPI; initial catalog=[database];Connection Timeout=1000
```

I also tried the same with SQL Server authentication

```
server=[machine]\\[instance]; uid=sa; pwd=[password]; initial catalog=[database];Connection Timeout=1000
```

None of the above worked out.

Comment: how do i show that, can you guide, i have the connection string in my website's web.config.

Comment: Can you show the debugger value of the connection string as well?

Comment: @CaiusJard i compared it, it's actually the same what i am using in my web.config.

Comment: @Stefan can you guide me how do i get you the debugger value?

Comment: If you're using visual studio, go to the code line where you use the connection string and press F9 (a red dit will appear). Next,  you can start debugging by pressing F5. The program will halt at the dot and you can inspect the value and see if its what you excpect

Comment: Please explain more accurately what this sentence means: *i am able to connect my project if i connect to my database located on the remote server. but the one on my local machine just does not works.*

Comment: The database on your local machine and the database on the remote server are different databases. You need to use the appropriate connection string for each

Comment: @CaiusJard i mean i am able to access production database hosted on another machine with it's own named instance and connection string, however when i use the named instance and connection string for local machine it does not work. The pattern is same for production and local connection string

Comment: The pattern is the same but the specifics are not. Your SSMS connects ok to the local machine? The same connection details will be used by .net. Post the full connectionstring, with a ***'d out password, that you're using to try and connect to the local machine and the error you get when you do

Comment: Another thing to try: make a new text file on your desktop, call it A.UDL, double click it and set the parameters just like you do in SSMS, get a working connection, then click OK and open the udl file in a text editor

Comment: I got it, i debugged the connection string value, and found the password was not being passed to the connection string, i made a check for the same and found the code had been explicitly passing the password which was being sent empty, this was however for one SQL Command only. but that was causing the issue.

Comment: Look at "manage user secrets" - keep the password out of the code

Comment: Learn to debug code. Stop assuming, stop rushing to judgement. Most problems are caused by application logic errors so you should assume the problem is in the code you write. And NO ONE should be using the SA login for development work. Bad habits!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, SSMS can connect using direct.
However, from asp.net, you in most cases have to turn on networking.

For reasons of secuirty, by default, your local instance of SQL server express has this feature turned off by default.

so, you need to do two things - and this was NOT required with older versions of sql server, but for recent versions - starting around 2012, you need to:

Turn on the browser service. This "translates" the sql "instance" to your IP address. (on startup, sql server assigns a IP address to that instance, but it will NOT be the same IP as your computer). But, the NAT translator thus has to be running.

That IP translator? It called the SQL browser service, and as noted, you need to have that running now, where as in the past you did not. That is this setting - launch the sql configuration, and you see this:

[image]

So, make sure the SQL Server Browser service is running - it is NOW required and as noted was not in the past.

Next up:

You need to turn on networking for SQL server. SSMS (sql studio) is able to connect using memory pipes - applications using the sql server provider in .net cannot!!!

So, once you ensured and checked the above browser service is running?

Then click on SQL server Networking Configuration, and turn on network connections (again, they are not turned on by default). That is this:

[image]

Now, after doing above, you probably should re-start sql server, and then the browser service. (just right click on sql server again, and choose this:

[image]

So, while SQL studio can connect using shared memory, .net and asp.net sites can't.

So, start the sql browser service - it is required to "resolve" the instance of sql server. in most cases, that will be SQLEXPRESS.

And consider using the built in connection builder in Visual Studio - it will not only build the connection string for you, but will also test the connection - and this can be done long before you even run any code.